# Name for algebraic structure like a field that's forgotten its multiplicative identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know a torsor is often called a "group that's forgotten its identity". Is there a name for a structure that's like a field that's forgotten its multiplicative identity?

Consider a field F and a vector space V on F equipped with a division operation that divides any vector by a non-zero vector to yield a scalar of F. This satisfies the obvious multiply/divide identities with the vector scaling function. There's an isomorphism between the vectors and the scalars for each non-zero vector that you pick as the "unit", but there's no canonical isomorphism.

I'm using this for physical quantities such as length, where one can add and scale lengths, but there is no canonical "unit length".

Comment: Having a little trouble guessing what you mean. You mean you want the field to "lose" both its additive and multiplicative identities? If you're just concerned about a single operation, then there doesn't really seem to be much difference between losing the identity of one operation over another. They're the same sort of thing written with different symbols.

Comment: I think you're essentially just asking for "one-dimensional vector space over $F$".

Comment: Agree with Hurkyl. The space has to be 1-dimensional. If $u$ and $v$ are two linearly independent vectors, and $u/v=\lambda\in F$, then how does the isomorphism tell the difference between $u$ and $\lambda v$?

Comment: I don't want to forget the additive identity, only the multiplicative identity. The space is also one-dimensional as it is isomorphic to F, but there is no canonical isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are forgetting just the multiplicative identity, the structure is a *$1$-dimensional vector space*, i.e. an abelian group $L$ equipped with an action $\alpha\colon F\otimes_{\mathbb Z} L\to L$ (this just means that $\alpha\colon F\times L\to L$ is bilinear for inteeger scalars) so that $\alpha(\mu(x,y),p)=\alpha(x,\alpha(y,p))$, $\alpha(1,p)=p$, and such that for some non-zero $p\in L$, $x\mapsto \alpha(x,p)$ is a bijection.

If you want to forget the additive identity as well, the resulting structure is an *affine line* $A$, which consists of an action $a\colon L\times A\to A$ so that $a(p_1+p_2,q)=a(p_1,a(p_2,q))$ and $a(0,q)=q$, such that for some non-zero $q$, $p\mapsto a(p,q)$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

One could say that [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) "forget length." Since the coordinates are given by $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}$ under the equivalence $v\sim w\iff \exists \lambda\in \Bbb R(w=\lambda v)$, equivalence classes contain elements of all lengths, so they forgot the lengths they began with.

Projective geometry uses homogeoneous coordinates. In the context of projective geometry, distance is not invariant.

---

Just as $\Bbb R^n$ acts faithfully and transitively on $\Bbb R^n$ by addition, making every point "as good as the origin," the scaling action of $\Bbb R$ on $X=\{\lambda v\mid \lambda\in \Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\}$ for a nonzero vector $v$ is transitive. This could be viewed as "the action of $\Bbb R$ making all vectors in $X$ as good as one another."

Answer (score 0):

The closest algebraic structure to what you asked foris a ring. Rings dont necessarily have a multiplicative identity. Notice that in that case there cant be inverses and is not a field, so you can't define a vector space over it.

Comment: Dear user130254 : If the user was just asking about algebraic structures not necessarily having identity, then "semigroups and rngs" would be the answer, yes, but it doesn't look like that's what the question is actually about. It looks like they're talking about the action of a group/field on a set, although it's unclear what they're looking for at the moment. Regards

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I should point out there are two common usages of the word "ring", which differ on whether or not $1$ and the identity axioms are part of the definition. In the other usage, what you described would usually be called a "rng" or a "$\mathbb{Z}$-algebra". I am very much under the impression that the usage you are using is somewhat old-fashioned (albeit still in relatively common use).